# Updating cuttent row in the datatable and adding new record ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This question is regarding updating current record in the database table and adding new record.

In my ASP.NET MVC application, from the view I have passed the relevant data to the controller, Here is my database table and highlighted the relevant record to be updated.

[image]

This is my controller, and there can see the data passed from the view.

[image]

[image]

So as the picture 1, ApprovalProcess_Id **40** should update with the today date, approval_status should be 1, Approval_note should update as well. As you can see picture 3 Note data is already there. So Approval_ProcessId is I got separately to the tempdata.

```
int tempAId = int.Parse(TempData.Peek("CurrentId").ToString());
```

The way I tried as the picture, isn't updating either, I want to update the note, approvestatus, datetime at the current record and need to add new record with the same **tempAID** with the model containing the new approver_Id.

This is my current code

```
public ActionResult ApproveRequest(ApprovalProcess approvalProcess)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (approvalProcess.Approvers != null)
            {
                int tempAId = int.Parse(TempData.Peek("CurrentId").ToString());

                ApprovalParty approvalParty = new ApprovalParty();
                approvalParty.Approved_Date = DateTime.Now;
                approvalParty.Approved_Note = approvalProcess.Approvers.ToList().First().Approved_Note;
                approvalParty.Approve_Status = true;
            }
            //approvalProcess approvalProcess1 = new approvalProcess();
            //approvalParty.Approved_Date = DateTime.Now;
            //approvalParty.Approve_Status = true;


            //ApprovalParty model = new ApprovalParty();
            
            ////approvalParty.ApprovalProcess_Id = tempAId;
            //approvalParty.Approved_Note = model.Approved_Note;

            //db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing any updates on the database at all which is to say you're updating all the properties in the world, but none of it is being pushed back to your database.

Here's an example that would push an update to your database:

```
public ActionResult ApproveRequest(ApprovalProcess approvalProcess)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int.TryParse(TempData.Peek("CurrentId").ToString(), out int tempAId);

        // This pulls the record from your db so that entity framework can track and update it.
        var approvalParty = db.ApprovalParties.Find(tempAId);
        approvalParty.Approval_Date = DateTime.Now;

        // This will error because you'd need to select a particular Approver in the list to determine which Approved_Note to use.
        // Should be something like Approvers.ToList()[0].Approved_Note
        approvalParty.Approved_Note == approvalProcess.Approvers.ToList().Approved_Note;
        approvalParty.Approve_Status = true;

        // Pushes the updated data to the database.
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

For adding a new ApprovalParty record (I'm just assuming this is what you're calling it, you'll do the property value mapping to a new ApprovalParty and add it to `db.ApprovalParties`:

```
var approvalParty = new ApprovalParty
{
    Approved_Date = DateTime.Now,
    Approved_Note = approvalProcess.Approvers.ToList()[0].Approved_Note,
    Approved_Status = true;
};

db.ApprovalParties.Add(approvalParty);
db.SaveChanges();
```